# Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I get the .crx file of an extension name [simulty](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simulty-the-internet-unde/gfbpggdmnikkiepjbfhnecphapgigifg) in order to edit the source ( for personal use )

So i have follow all the steps :
get .crx
unzip .crx
Load in Google chrome extension
But when i try to load i have the same error " Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata " 
There is a _metadata and a *locales files in the directy and it seems that google chrome don't want to load it. Is there any way to take off the "*" ... and load it ? I heard that its a google chrome bug...

Anybody find the solution ?
Or know any other way to edit the source of an chrome extension?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just delete the `_metadata` folder when loading an unpacked extension.

It contains cryptographic hashes of files to ensure they have not been modified. It is not expected to be present for an unpacked extension (it's automatically added by CWS when generating a `crx`), so just delete it.

I would also suggest editing the manifest to wipe `update_url` and `key` fields (if present), to completely dissociate with the original extension.

Comment: Yes, just delete the line.

Comment: Do i have to complety delete the update_url line ? " "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx", " ? Moreover i didn't find the key field ...